# zsh path is gone

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am working with a MacBook Pro. I installed Homebrew, Bash, VS Code, Oh-my-zsh and iTerminal. I am able to use the iTerminal. And, the integrated terminal on VS Code with bash. But, when I open a terminal in VS code with zsh the terminal is blank. No file system and it reads no commands. I can use the VS code with bash instead of zsh. I tried checking the VS code alias and settings but everything seemed okay. What would be the next steps?

I tried setting a user profile. I tried updating the path in VS Code. I removed VS code and reinstalled. I checked that zsh is my default  and working on iterminal. I can make commands and run zsh on the terminal.